# raspbian SD card flashed - now how to set up SSH headlessly?

Tags: raspbian

I've flashed a Raspbian (2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img) image onto an SD card using my mac running Mavericks 10.9.1 and in the absence of a monitor etc. am trying to set it up headlessly on my local network.

At the moment the Pi is refusing SSH connections, so the only access I have is via my mac's SD card reader.

If I could see the 'standard' *nix file structure I could edit the relevant files to allow SSH access, but whenever I insert the card into my mac all I can see are files like

```
.                    bootcode.bin         issue.txt
..                   cmdline.txt          kernel.img
.Trashes             config.txt           kernel_emergency.img
._.Trashes           fixup.dat            start.elf
.fseventsd           fixup_cd.dat         start_cd.elf
LICENSE.oracle       fixup_x.dat          start_x.elf
```

Where can I go from here? Can I just add some config file into this directory..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it - the trick is to install OSXFUSE and execute

sudo mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/DISKNAME

Comment: And for completeness, in order to enable SSH I then ran http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/enabling-ssh-on-rpi-without-screen-keystrokes-for-raspi-config from my mac

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you can't login via ssh; it's enabled by default. If DHCP is on, and you hooked it into your router, login to your router to see which IP it was assigned. Then ssh into it using the default username and pass: pi/raspberry.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but for some reason it was not the case.